# See the Unicode code point of the current character

Tags: statusline, unicode, encoding

How can I see the Unicode code point of the character where the cursor is? For example, if my cursor is on a `⌘` character, I'd like Vim to tell me that it is [U+2318](https://codepoints.net/U+2318).

Alternative information, such as the base-10 representation (8984) or the UTF-8 representation (E2 8C 98) would be acceptable.

I ask about Unicode and UTF-8 because they are most common, but if the answer generalizes to other character sets and encodings, that would be good to know as well.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use `%b` or `%B` in `statusline` or `rulerformat`. From [`:help statusline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27statusline%27):

```
b N   Value of character under cursor. 
B N   As above, in hexadecimal.
```

For example:

```
set statusline=%b\ 0x%B
```

Gives you:

```
8984 0x2318
```

Another way is to use `ga` or the `:ascii` command. From [`:help ga`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#ga):

```
:as[cii]        or                                      ga :as :ascii
ga                      Print the ascii value of the character under the
                        cursor in decimal, hexadecimal and octal.
```

Which will give you:

```
<⌘> 8984, Hex 2318, Octal 21430
```

Another useful mapping is `g8`:

```
e2 8c 98
```

Which prints the hex value of the actual bytes stored in the file (this command assumes UTF-8).

In addition there are some plugins you could use:

- [unicode.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) adds various useful unicode-related commands. Use `:UnicodeName` to get details of the character under the cursor.
- [characterize.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-characterize); this expands the `ga` command with the unicode name, similar to unicode.vim.
- My own [uni](https://github.com/arp242/uni) CLI tool has a little [Vim integration script](https://github.com/arp242/uni/blob/master/uni.vim) which provides `:UnicodeName` from unicode.vim (but none of the other features).

Comment: "this command assumes UTF-8" - the documentation says this, but my experience is that it works in any `encoding` (but does not respect `fileencoding`).

Comment: After further experimentation, a if `encoding` is set to a non-utf8 multibyte encoding such as cp932, `g8` will only print the first byte, but `ga` will show the full character number.

Comment: Is there a way to have the output of g8 appear in statusline by itself? Kinda of like the original question with the "alternative information" part.