# ci" and ci' not working

Tags: key-bindings

`ci(`, `ci{`, `ci<`, etc. work but `ci"` and `ci'` do nothing. The text inside the speech marks is not deleted and I am not put into insert mode.

I have a Dell laptop running Ubuntu OS with the standard British English key mapping.

edit: I think the problem may have been that I was trying to edit curly quotation marks aka smart quotes rather than regular quotation marks. The text I was practising on was copy&pasted from the internet whereas when I type the quotes for myself the commands do then work when I want to edit what's inside.

Comment: An example, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to watch out for:

1. Make sure you're not using a keyboard layout with "[dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)"; i.e. does pressing a single `'` or `"` actually insert that character, or do you need to use `"<Space>`? If it's the latter, your keyboard layout has dead keys, and you must use `ci"<Space>` for Vim normal mode commands as well.
2. Make sure that the characters are actually `'` (0x27) and `"` (0x22) and not `“` (U+201C or 0xe2 0x80 0x9c in UTF-8) or `‘` (U+2018, 0xe2 0x80 0x98) or any other quote variant.

   Check it by using the `g8` or `ga` command, or for more information use the [unicode.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) plugin (also see [See the Unicode code point of the current character](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/555/51)).