# Replace nbsp with none string in utf-8 encoding in vim

Tags: substitute, unicode

The `nbsp`(non breaking space)'s binary format in utf-8 encoding is `c2a0`.
Create a sample.txt this way :input  `it is a test` then `ctrl+v+u a0`,then you get the sample test file.

```
xxd sample.txt
00000000: 6974 2069 7320 6120 7465 7374 c2a0 0a  it is a test....
```

Now show the current encoding with `set encoding`,it is `encoding=utf-8`,i want to replace the `nbsp` with none string,it make me confused that

```
:%s/\%uc2\%ua0//
"the above command can't replace nbsp with none string in utf-8 encoding
:%s/\%ua0//
"%s/\%ua0//  can replace it
```

In utf-8 encoding why `%s/\%ua0//`  can replace nbsp with none string  instead of `%s/\%uc2\%ua0//` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You almost never need to deal with the binary UTF-8 encoding in Vim (or indeed, almost anywhere, including programming languages); for the most part you can just forget it exists as Vim takes cares of all of that for you: you just need to deal with the Unicode codepoints.

You can think of Unicode codepoints as the "human interface" and UTF-8 as one of several technical implementations. It's roughly similar to files on your disk: you use the same tools to create, edit, copy, and move files, and you don't deal with the filesystem format directly (ext4, NTFS, FAT, etc.) UTF-8 is like the filesystem.

At any rate, the codepoint for the non-breaking space is `U+00A0`, so you can just use that, as you already discovered:

```
%s/\%ua0//
```

You can leave our the two leading zeros, although you can also include them if you want.

In this case it may look confusing since `U+00A0` and `0xc2 0xa0` look kinda similar, but this is just an artefact of how UTF-8 encodes things (it's actually quite clever in many ways; the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples) can probably explain that better than I can).

---

[See the Unicode code point of the current character](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/560/51) may also be useful. If you want a CLI tool to know which codepoints are in a file then I actually [wrote a little tool for this](https://github.com/arp242/uni/); here's a [web demo](https://arp242.github.io/uni-wasm/#run%3Ai%20it%20is%20a%20test%C2%A0) for your specific example.